# What is the blue bubble around paladins?

Tags: orcs-must-die

It only lasts until he attacks, so it doesn't appear to be an effective shield as I would first guess. I had 8-10 paladin guardians at the time, and only 1 ever had this happen.

[image: screenshot of paladin with blue bubble]

**What is this shield/aura the paladin has around him? What does it do?**

EDIT: The paladin also had this aura active between waves, so I don't think it is related to any kind of enemy. Proof: the "2" in the screenshot below is the countdown to the next wave.

[image: second screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, I've seen that effect when a Paladin is being hit by something it can't counterattack (ranged flying enemies). This usually ends one of a few ways:

- Something comes within melee range and the Paladin beats on it instead.
- The Paladin dies.

Comment: The paladin had that aura between waves, so I'm not sure about this answer... but maybe he was like that at the end of the previous wave and it just got stuck that way?

Comment: Possibly. I'm not anywhere I can test it, though. Once I am, I plan on plopping a Pally somewhere where I can watch him get attacked by air units and see if he reacts like I expect and if he takes less damage while it is up.

Comment: I did some testing and this is correct, minus your second bullet point. It seems the shield lasts until the paladin either attacks or dies, so it can persist through waves. Though I haven't been able to tell how much it reduces incoming damage.

Comment: Removed my second bullet point!